# Visual Studio hotkey for exclude file from build

Tags: visual-studio

I'm just wondering about this feature because It gives me too stress if you have some source that need to exclude from build sparsely or often :*( 
I searched Visual Studio key sets but I can't find it I think this feature is not in Visual Studio...
does anyone know about this feature? please help me!